# How to set my SQLHelper as Singleton

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-sqlite

I was wondering if it was possible to have my SQLHelper that extends from SQLiteOpenHelper as Singleton class.

my problem is :

To use an object which the class extends from SQLiteOpenHelper we need to pass a context which is "this" when i instantiate my class.
The fact is that i would like to use my Helper wherever i want without having to instantiate it again ...

If someone as a solution for me ilustrated with an example, that would be nice :)

thank you !

Here is the class i have for the moment and which i'd like to have as Singleton:

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

/*
 Attributs
*/

public SQLHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 23);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORIES + "(" + CATEGORY_NAME + " TEXT," + CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER, " + CATEGORY_ID_PARENT + " INTEGER," + CATEGORY_URL_IMAGE + " TEXT" + ")" ;
    String CREATE_TABLE_INFOS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INFOS + "(" + INFOS_AGE + " INTEGER," + INFOS_MAIL + " TEXT," + INFOS_DISPLAY_PRICE + " TEXT," + INFOS_TOKEN + " TEXT," + INFOS_REFRESH_TOKEN + " TEXT," + INFOS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION + " TEXT, " + INFOS_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION + " TEXT, " + INFOS_APP_VERSION + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + "(" + ITEM_ID + " INTEGER," + ITEM_NAME + " TEXT," + ITEM_CATEGORY_ID + " INTEGER," + ITEM_PRICE + " REAL" + ")";
    String CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST + "(" + SHOPPING_LIST_ID + " INTEGER," + SHOPPING_LIST_NAME + " TEXT," + SHOPPING_LIST_DATE_CREATION + " TEXT" + ")";
    String CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS + "(" + SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS_LIST_ID + " INTEGER," + SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS_ID + " INTEGER," + SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS_NB_ITEMS + " INTEGER," + SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS_CHECKED + " INTEGER" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIES);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_INFOS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CATEGORIES);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_INFOS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SHOPPING_LIST_ITEMS);
    onCreate(db);
}
/*
 Methods
*/
}
```

Comment: While using a sigleton seems like a good idea at first, they are generally considered bad practice: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil

Comment: Generally a `Context` is available all over in Android apps. In places where it isn't easily available, you shouldn't be doing database operations anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO - In a round about way you answered your own question. Because you need to supply an argument, in this case a `context`, to create the `SQLiteHelper` the singleton pattern will not work since each time you initialize an object it must be different. Singletons work only when a single, identical object, is needed to coordinate functions across the system, not just when you only want one copy of an object.

Could you force the code such that only one copy of your `SQLiteHelper` exists? Sure - take a look below:

```
private static volatile Class mClass  null;

public static Class getInstance(Context context){
    if(mClass == null){
        synchronized(Class.class){
            if(mClass == null){
                mClass = new Class(context);
            }
        }
    }
    return mClass;
}
```

You'd think this was a good idea at first. It looks like a legitimate way to create a singleton (though according to *Effective Java* there are better ways to do this like using an `enum` type). You will in fact get only one copy of Class initialized. The problem is that the `context` will be wrong in every case except the first. You don't have to be an expert on singletons to realize that's just a bad idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "using an enum type" ?

Comment: Because there can only be one instance of an enum, it can be used as a way to create a singleton pattern. [Here's a brief description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_Enum_way) from wikipedia but I suggest you check out the full explanation in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, but I don't think it`s a good idea:

```
private static DataBaseHelper instance;

private DataBaseHelper() {
    super(App.getAppContext(), DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
}   

public static DataBaseHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DataBaseHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for a private constructor and getInstance Method

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static SQLHelper sqlHelper = null;

private SQLHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 23);
}

public static SQLHelper getInstance(){
if(sqlHelper == null){
sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(context);
return sqlHelper;
}
return sqlHelper;
}
```